# Angular - "if" block rendered after document ready

Tags: angularjs

I've got HTML along the lines of:

```
<form ng-if="submitted != true">
   ...
</form>
```

Then I have Angular code that carries out actions on that form, supposedly after the DOM is ready.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  $('form').setupSomePlugin();
  ...
  $('form').on('submit', function () {
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.submitted = true;
    });
  });
  ...
```

So the effect is, upon submit, the form hides itself. The result of `submitted != true` is definitely true, and the form gets displayed, but apparently it's rendering the form somehow after the `angular.element(document).ready` callback. How is that possible, and how do I fix this so that `$('form').doThings()` fires only after the form with the `ng-if` condition on it is fully rendered?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to say exactly what might be wrong. If I had to guess, I'd say that you're trying to update parts of `$scope` outside of Angular's digest cycle (which means Angular won't pick up the change). Either that or the value really isn't what you think.

Comment: Proprietary stuff, can't show much more, though I did change a variable. So basically, once the submit button has been hit, it sets $scope.submitted to true (within a $timeout callback so there's no digest issue). That part absolutely works. The problem is that the form doesn't exist right away, even within document-ready. I know because I did `console.log($('form'))` and it returned zero results. But if I open the browser console and manually type that in, then I do get a result.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Added more code

Comment: How is the form constructed then? If it's via angular, then you should be using `ng-submit` to handle the form's submit event rather than trying to listen to the element.

Comment: The submission is kind of irrelevant. The main issue here is that if I call a jQuery plugin on the form (see above - `setupSomePlugin()`), it doesn't work because the form doesn't exist yet because it's inside an `ng-if` that apparently has yet to evaluate.

Comment: The form does render but it takes a split second. I need a `$(document).ready()` type call, but that triggers once all ng conditional elements are rendered.